# Custom contours on DEM

Tags: dem, lidar, contour

I've made a DEM using LIDAR, and I'd like to mark specified contours on it as polylines.

Is there a way I can create custom contours for specific heights OD?

I can use either QGIS or ArcGIS Pro to do this.

Comment: Please decide regarding the software :)

Comment: I have access to either, but might be easier to do in QGIS as I don't have some tools lisenced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GRASS you can use [r.contour](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.contour.html) to pass a list of contour levels to create.

Or you could just create contours every 1 m, then extract by attributes.